# Discrete Bayes Net learning under parameter constraints

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bayesian-network, maximum-entropy, constrained-optimization

What is some relevant research available on estimating the parameters of a Bayes Net (**with known structure**) when there are known constraints on conditional and marginal probabilities?

For example, consider a simple example of the Bayes Net over 4 boolean variables {A, B, C, D} with the DAG structure A->C, B->C, C->D, where it is known that $P(D=1|A=0) = 0.2$, $P(C=1|B=1) = 0.8$.

We would like to estimate the full joint distribution -- either using maximum entropy **under these constraints**, or maximum likelihood from data (with possible missing values) with the resulting joint **respecting the constraints**.

I would also like the learning algorithm to produce a certificate of infeasibility if given constraints are mutually inconsistent.

What is a good way to approach this **general** problem?

I am trying to determine the most general case where fast algorithms are known, and any negative results in this area.

I have already encountered:

1. [Bayesian Network Learning with Parameter Constraints, Niculescu et. al.](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume7/niculescu06a/niculescu06a.pdf)
2. [Maximum Entropy Distributions between Upper and Lower Bounds, Abbas](http://yaroslavvb.com/papers/abbas-maximum.pdf)

Comment: I like this question as I would like to learn more from this and the simple example is a good way to start thinking about these problems. There is one difficulty/issue that I encounter at my current attempt of trying to understand the problem: You state $P(C=1|B=1) = 0.8$ but this means that, when $B=1$, then $A$ has no relationship with $C$, am I right? Or are we considering the statement $P(C=1|B=1) = 0.8$ as being dependent on a particular fixed distribution of $A$, and for different distributions of $A$ you would not get the same $P(C=1|B=1)$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Let's wait to hear from the OP, but to my eye $P(C=1|B=1)$ is a statement about marginal probabilities.

Comment: That's right. The problem is to arrive at the joint given constraints on marginals and conditionals. The structure of the Bayes Net itself imposes several constraints.